# Wordpress Plugin unable to pull in user email variable in array value

Tags: php

Editing a no longer supported WordPress plugin that has nearly the functionality I need. The CRANE APP Jira Integration plugin allows one to display a table of Jira issues on a page using a shortcode. One of the shortcode's attributes defines in Jira what issues to display via JQL(Jira Query Language). My goal is to edit the plugin so that the current logged in user's email is included in the plugin's JQL statement. The hope is that whoever is logged in will see on the page all the issues they have reported.

The below code fails to deliver any Jira issues. I need to call the logged in user's email address and added to:

```
array ( 'jql' => 'reporter = $user_email AND...
```

I'm also using Ultimate Member plugin which has an um_fetch_user function which I have also tried and failed.

```
function ca_ji_shortcodes_init() {

    // pulling in user

    add_action('wp_loaded', function() {

  // stuff here where you get user id

  $user_data = get_userdata( $userid );

  // stuff here
  um_fetch_user( get_current_user_id() );
        $email = um_user('user_email');

});

    // Adding shortcode for default Jira integration
    function ca_ji_shortcode_default( $atts, $content, $tag ) {
        // Normalizing attribute keys
        $atts = array_change_key_case( ( array ) $atts, CASE_LOWER );
        // Overriding default attributes
        $atts = shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'jql' => 'reporter = '.$user_data->user_email.' AND resolution = unresolved ORDER BY updated DESC',
                'col_fields' => 'status,summary',
                'col_labels' => __( 'Status', 'crane-app-jira-integration' ) . ',' . __( 'Summary', 'crane-app-jira-integration' ),
                'more_fields' => 'summary,description',
                'more_labels' => __( 'Summary', 'crane-app-jira-integration' ) . ',' . __( 'Description', 'crane-app-jira-integration' )
            ),
            $atts,
            $tag
        );
```

Comment: Have you checked the result of get_userdata? Is the user found? Also try to print the result of the jql row in the array to see if the query looks correct.

Comment: No, I pulled in a snippet I found here that suggested a means to pull in the user data in a plugin.

Comment: Try my suggestion and post the results

Comment: Ok so I printed the JQL row and it appears my variable was empty... no email printed in the JQL, which was otherwise correct.

I also tried printing just the $email variable, empty, and print $user_data->user_email, still empty so I must not be pulling in the field correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Thanks for suggesting to print...

```
function ca_ji_shortcodes_init() {


// Adding shortcode for default Jira integration
function ca_ji_shortcode_default( $atts, $content, $tag ) {
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    // Normalizing attribute keys
    $atts = array_change_key_case( ( array ) $atts, CASE_LOWER );
    // Overriding default attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'jql' => 'reporter = \'' . $current_user->user_email . '\' AND resolution = unresolved ORDER BY updated DESC',
```